# RestSharp: ItemChoice always null

Tags: c#, xml, subsonic, restsharp

I'm new to RestSharp and trying to access my subsonic server through the [subsonic-api](http://www.subsonic.org/pages/api.jsp). 
Every Response in wrapped in a subsonic-response Tag, e.g.

```
<subsonic-response xmlns="http://subsonic.org/restapi"
               status="ok" version="1.10.1">
<artists ignoredArticles="The El La Los Las Le Les">
    <index name="A">
        <artist id="5449" name="A-Ha" coverArt="ar-5449" albumCount="4"/>
        <artist id="5421" name="ABBA" coverArt="ar-5421" albumCount="6"/>
        <artist id="5432" name="AC/DC" coverArt="ar-5432" albumCount="15"/>
        <artist id="6633" name="Aaron Neville" coverArt="ar-6633" albumCount="1"/>
    </index>
    <index name="B">
        <artist id="5950" name="Bob Marley" coverArt="ar-5950" albumCount="8"/>
        <artist id="5957" name="Bruce Dickinson" coverArt="ar-5957" albumCount="2"/>
    </index>
</artists>
```

Xsd generated the following classes for serialization:

```
 public partial class Response
{

    private object itemField;

    private ItemChoiceType itemElementNameField;

    private ResponseStatus statusField;

    private string versionField;

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlChoiceIdentifierAttribute("ItemElementName")]
    public object Item
    {
        get
        {
            return this.itemField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.itemField = value;
        }
    }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    public ItemChoiceType ItemElementName
    {
        get
        {
            return this.itemElementNameField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.itemElementNameField = value;
        }
    }

    public ResponseStatus status
    {
        get
        {
            return this.statusField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.statusField = value;
        }
    }

    public string version
    {
        get
        {
            return this.versionField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.versionField = value;
        }
    }
}

public partial class ArtistsID3
{

    private List<IndexID3> indexField;

    public ArtistsID3()
    {
        this.indexField = new List<IndexID3>();
    }

    public List<IndexID3> index
    {
        get
        {
            return this.indexField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.indexField = value;
        }
    }
}

 public enum ItemChoiceType
{

    /// <remarks/>
    album,

    /// <remarks/>
    albumList,

--- snip ----
```

When I'm trying to deserialize into a Response-Object the field Item is always null and ItemElementName gets the first value from the enum ItemChoiceType but version and status are correctly set. The retrieved xml-output looks like expected (see sample).
What works though is deserializing into ArtistsID3 but then I loose the status.

Here's the code:

```
SubsonicApi api = new SubsonicApi();
var request = new RestRequest();
request.Resource = "getArtists.view";
request.AddParameter("v", "1.10.2");
request.AddParameter("c", "no name yet");
// Item always null!
// var response = api.Execute<Response>(request);
var response = api.Execute<ArtistsID3>(request);

public T Execute<T>(RestRequest request)
        where T : new()
    {
        var client = new RestClient();
        client.BaseUrl = new System.Uri(BaseUrl);
        client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator(_accountSid, _secretKey);
        var response = client.Execute<T>(request);
        Console.WriteLine("RESPONSE-DATA: " + response.Content);
        return response.Data;
     }
```

I'd be glad if somebody could point me in the right direction as I think the right way should be accessing the data through an Response object. Really don't know how to debug this not expected behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SubsonicResponse subsonicResponse = new SubsonicResponse()
            {
                status = "ok",
                version = "1.10.1",
                artists = new Artists()
                {
                    ignoredArticles = "The El La Los Las Le Les",
                    indexes = new List<Index>() {
                        new Index() {
                            name = "A", artists = new List<Artist>() {
                                new Artist() { id = 5449, name = "A-Ha", converArt = "ar-5449", albumCount = 4},
                                new Artist() { id = 5221, name = "ABBA", converArt = "ar-5421", albumCount = 6},
                                new Artist() { id = 5432, name = "AC/DC", converArt = "ar-5432", albumCount = 15},
                                new Artist() { id = 6633, name = "Aaron Neville", converArt = "ar-5633", albumCount = 1}
                            }
                        },
                        new Index() {
                            name = "B", artists = new List<Artist>() {
                                new Artist() { id = 5950, name = "Bob Marley", converArt = "ar-5950", albumCount = 8},
                                new Artist() { id = 5957, name = "Bruce Dickinson", converArt = "ar-5957", albumCount = 2}
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }
            };
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SubsonicResponse));

            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(FILENAME);
            XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
            ns.Add("", "http://subsonic.org/restapi");

            serializer.Serialize(writer, subsonicResponse, ns);
            writer.Flush();
            writer.Close();
            writer.Dispose();

            XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SubsonicResponse));
            XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(FILENAME);
            SubsonicResponse newSResponse = (SubsonicResponse)xs.Deserialize(reader);

        }
    }
    [XmlRoot("subsonic-response", Namespace = "http://subsonic.org/restapi")]
    public class SubsonicResponse
    {
        [XmlAttribute("status")]
        public string status { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute("version")]
        public string version { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("artists")]
        public Artists artists { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "artists")]
    public class Artists
    {
        [XmlAttribute("ignoredArticles")]
        public string ignoredArticles { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("index")]
        public List<Index> indexes { get; set; }
    }
    [XmlRoot("index")]
    public class Index
    {
        [XmlAttribute("name")]
        public string  name { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("artist")]
        public List<Artist> artists { get; set; }
    }
    [XmlRoot("artist")]
    public class Artist
    {
       [XmlAttribute("id")]
        public int  id { get; set; }

       [XmlAttribute("name")]
        public string  name { get; set; }

       [XmlAttribute("converArt")]
        public string  converArt { get; set; }

       [XmlAttribute("albumCount")]
        public int  albumCount { get; set; }
    }
}
​
```

Comment: Thanks, going down the more manual route is working fine, using your classes RestSharp is (De)serializing fine. I've added one more field (license) to SubsonicResponse to test if it works with other api calls and it's doing fine.

Comment: If you can serialize then you should always be able to de-serialize with same classes and data.  That is why I like to serialize first and verify the xml file is good.